# Twig include : use translation in the passed argument

Tags: php, symfony, twig, twig-extension

This works fine

```
{% include 'site/snippet.html.twig'
    with {'description': 'Some text'}
%}
```

But how to get this to work? **Using a translation as argument**

```
{% include 'site/snippet.html.twig'
    with {'description': '{{ 'solutions.description' | trans }}'}
%}
```

The snippet.html content is:

```
<p>
    {{ description }}
</p>
```

And calling the translation `{{ 'solutions.description' | trans }}` alone shows the content as expected.

What syntax would it be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to wrap the string in an extra set of `{{ }}`. Actually it should work like:

```
with {'description': 'solutions.description'|trans}
```